# Run PHP helper script from editor

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-code

Are [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) the way to launch helper PHP scripts from Visual Studio Code? If so, what should the task look like?

I've tried this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Data / Import",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "php",
            "args": [
                "data/bin/import.php"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The script runs but I get prompted for output scanning every time (not sure If I can just answer `never scan`) and `"files.encoding": "windows1252"` in workspace settings is ignored (output is apparently handled as UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing, it seems that choosing `process` as task type is mostly cosmetic and it still executes the script though a terminal. Project and file encodings are disregarded and task output is assumed to be in the default DOS codepage (here in Western Europe that typically means good old [850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)).

Task must be the way to run helper scripts because there's no other way. Perhaps you need to set `"type": "shell"` so you can [set the encoding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_changing-the-encoding-for-a-task-output) (at the price of having to escape everything manually) but couldn't get a syntax that works for PHP.